# Meaning of Euripides quote

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, quotes

The quote would be

> "Every man is like the company he is wont to keep."

What is the meaning of "he is wont to keep" in this quote? Merriam-Webster translates *wont* as *accustomed, used* or *inclined, apt*, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You are like the friends and acquaintances you choose to spend time with.

Comment: wont is in the dictionary.

Comment: @Lambie I know that, I even wrote it in the question, if you read it: "Merriam-Webster translates wont as accustomed, used or inclined, apt,...".
What is your point with this comment?

Comment: My point is trust the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that "**We are (become) like the company we keep**". The usage "**wont**" is an old usage - even though it is still used today. It generally means ***most often or habitually*** (i.e. commonly done for any reason - habit, inclination, desire, or forced).

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wont

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wont+to

Comment: Wont may be somewhat old-fashioned, but is live usage in literary and academic use. Saying it is Middle English is misleading.